# How do I install TweetDeck?

Tags: apt, 64-bit, dependencies, adobe-air

See question here: ===============> https://superuser.com/questions/218868/tweetdeck-adobe-air-on-ubuntu-10-10

Getting the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 tweetdeckfast.fff259dc0ce2657847bbb4aff0e62062efc56543.1 : PreDepends: adobeair (>= 1.5.3.0) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed this and it worked fine http://support.tweetdeck.com/entries/181425-how-to-install-air-tweetdeck-in-linux-ubuntu-variants

Comment: You mean that you installed via the RPM instead of the deb?

Comment: No, they used the .bin file (which is an excecutable file that installs the application). It is generally recommended to use the package management system (Ubuntu Software Centre / apt-get / Synaptic / .deb files) instead because it is easier to uninstall/upgrade/reinstall that way.

Comment: The problem is with the deb, it is doing dependencies on adobeair that Ubuntu package manager isn't correctly made aware of.  Installing via the bin gets it installed, of course uninstall will be more difficult now.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to install TweetDeck and Adobe Air.**

**Adobe Air Installation:**

- [**[image] Get Adobe Air from this link.**](http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/lin/download/latest/AdobeAIRInstaller.bin)
- You need Getlibs which helps to install 32-bit libraries in a 64-bit environment.
- [**Save the getlibs-all.deb file from this link and double-click to install it.**](http://frozenfox.freehostia.com/cappy/getlibs-all.deb)
- Now you want to Install the dependencies for Adobe Air.Copy/Paste the following in terminal.

  `sudo apt-get install lib32asound2 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 libc6 libc6-i386 lib32nss-mdns`
- Now copy and paste each of the following commands into a terminal one at a time.

  `sudo getlibs -l libnss3.so.1d`
  `sudo getlibs -l libnssutil3.so.1d`
  `sudo getlibs -l libsmime3.so.1d`
  `sudo getlibs -l libssl3.so.1d`
  `sudo getlibs -l libnspr4.so.0d`
  `sudo getlibs -l libplc4.so.0d`
  `sudo getlibs -l libplds4.so.0d`
  `sudo getlibs -l libgnome-keyring.so`
  `sudo getlibs -l libgnome-keyring.so.0`
  `sudo getlibs -l libgnome-keyring.so.0.1.1`
- Move the Adobe Air.bin to your home folder.
- Open **terminal** and type the following command to make the file executable.

  **chmod +x AdobeAIRInstaller.bin**
- Install it using the following command

  **sudo ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin**
- Also type the following command in terminal

`sudo cp /opt/"Adobe Air"/Versions/1.0/Resources/libadobecertstore.so /usr/lib32`

- Run this command in terminal **sudo ldconfig** and you are done.

**TweetDeck Installation:**

- [**[image] Goto this page and click Install TweetDeck.**](http://www.tweetdeck.com/desktop/)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.