# How to install Getlibs

Tags: adobe-air

I'm trying to follow [This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/16581/78647) to install [Tweetdeck 0.38.2](http://www.oldapps.com/tweetdeck.php?old_tweetdeck=7149) on Ubuntu 12.04.

The problem is, the website they link to for downloading Getlibs, has been deleted by the host.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an alternate download link, or another way to install Getlibs?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Nathan Campbell's](https://askubuntu.com/users/63903/nathan-campbell) answer to this question:  [Wine can't find gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127848/wine-cant-find-gnome-keyring-pkcs11-so)

Getlibs can be found here: https://launchpad.net/~jcollins/+archive/jaminppa/+build/1482994/+files/getlibs_2.06-0ubuntu1%7Eppa2_all.deb